# Highlight the highest number in each row of the table

Tags: jquery

I want to highlight the highest number in each row of the table. I want to use css class `.max`. But I need to avoid searching in the 1st column and in the 1st row and also to omit empty cells.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.max {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ITEMS</th>
    <th>SHOP1</th>
    <th>SHOP2</th>
    <th>SHOP3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>ITEM1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>1,333333</th>
    <th>1,5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>ITEM2</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>ITEM3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>20</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work you can loop through each row and create an array of the values in the cells, converting them to floats as you go. Then you can use `reduce()` to get the index of the cell with the highest value and adding the class to it.

Note that I amended the HTML slightly to make selecting the relevant cells easier. Namely separated the header cells and body using `thead` and `tbody` respectively, and also changing the cells we want to target to `td` instead of `th`. Try this:

```js
$('tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $tds = $(this).find('td');
  var values = $tds.map(function() {
    return parseFloat($(this).text().trim().replace(',', '.'));
  }).get();
  $tds.eq(values.reduce((iMax, x, i, arr) => x > arr[iMax] ? i : iMax, 0)).addClass('max');
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.max {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ITEMS</th>
      <th>SHOP1</th>
      <th>SHOP2</th>
      <th>SHOP3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>ITEM1</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1,333333</td>
      <td>1,5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>ITEM2</th>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>ITEM3</th>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sure you want to replace the commas with periods? Seems like you should just strip them.

Comment: No, they need to be replaced. In certain numerical notations the `,` is used in place of the `.`. You need to replace them as JS will throw an error if you try to parse that. If I just strip them `1,3333` becomes `13333` instead of `1.333` that it needs to be.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense of `1,5`.